# Who are all these Wheel of Time characters?

Tags: character-identification, the-wheel-of-time

Earlier today I was shown the following picture in chat, some fan art of various Wheel of Time characters:

[image]

Some of them, of course, are easy to identify: Rand, Mat, Tuon, Thom Merrilin, and Elayne are all almost instantly identifiable. But I struggled with some of the others, including many of the women.

### Who are all these characters?

For ease of reference, [here's a numbered version of the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ft1yW.jpg).

Comment: What happened to your shirt?

Comment: @CHEESE I took it off, to: a) practice the forms with my sword, b) show off my Dragon tattoos to prove I'm the *Car'a'carn*, or c) impress the ladies. Not necessarily in that order.

Comment: thank you for the clarification, I currently have the means to do none of those, so I was baffled.

Comment: Well, before checking who asked this, I was totally thinking, "oh Rand's got this."

Comment: Am I the only one who thinks this depiction of Berelain blows Lanfear out of the water?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

1. [Moiraine Damodred.](http://wot.wikia.com/wiki/Moiraine_Damodred)

   Moiraine's description the first time Rand sees her:

   > The wide hood of her cloak framed her face and dark hair, hanging in soft ringlets. He had never seen a grown woman with her hair unbraided;  Her clothes were just as strange. Her cloak was sky-blue velvet, with thick silver embroidery, leaves and vines and flowers, all along the edges. Her dress gleamed faintly as she moved, a darker blue than the cloak, and slashed with cream. A necklace of heavy gold links hung around her neck, while another gold chain, delicate and fastened in her hair, supported a small, sparkling blue stone in the middle of her forehead. *-Eye of the World*

   Note the heavy use of blue in her clothing, the gem on her forehead, and the brown hair.

   [image]
2. [Egwene al'Vere.](http://wot.wikia.com/wiki/Egwene_al'Vere)

   > She was about 5'3" tall, with large brown eyes and dark hair. *-Companion*

   Egwene is described as being short, with darker skin, most likely tanned, She has long dark hair, usually referenced as being not braided (this is an oddity because she wanted to braid her hair her whole life till she met Moiraine). As noted in comments, we can see the dream *ter'angreal* around her neck, symbolic of her ability as a Dreamer, and past owner.

   [image]
3. [Fortuona Athaem Devi Paendrag.](http://wot.wikia.com/wiki/Tuon)

   > she was 4'11" tall and almost boyishly slim. Her face was heart-shaped and quite beautiful, with large, liquid eyes of a chocolate brown; her hair was silky black and straight. She had full lips and a very dark complexion. Her personality was quiet, reserved and thoughtful; *-Companion*

   Note her dark skin, hair, and full lips. Her position next to Mat also helps. The artist's depiction is not the best since she typically shaves her head.

   [image]
4. [Matrim Cauthon](http://wot.wikia.com/wiki/Matrim_Cauthon)

   > Approximately 5'11" tall and weighing 170 pounds, he had brown eyes and brown hair long enough to reach his coat collar. *-Companion*

   Note his characteristic wide brimmed hat; that alone sells this as Mat.

   [image]
5. [Uno Nomesta](http://wot.wikia.com/wiki/Uno)

   > a thick fellow with his head shaved except for a grizzled topknot. [...] The shaven-headed man had a villainous look; a long scar sliced down his left cheek, and a patch over that eye was painted with a scowling red replacement. Few of the men she had seen here were armed with more than a belt knife, but he wore a sword strapped to his back, the long hilt rising above his right shoulder. -*The Fires of Heaven*

   Bald with topknot, red eye-patch on his left eye.

   [image]
6. [Thomdril Merrilin](http://wot.wikia.com/wiki/Thomdril_Merrilin)

   > The white-haired man whirled, cloak flaring. His long coat had odd, baggy sleeves and big pockets. Thick mustaches, as snowy as the hair on his head, quivered around his mouth, and his face was gnarled like a tree that had seen hard times. He gestured imperiously at Rand and the others with a long-stemmed pipe, ornately carved, that trailed a wisp of smoke. Blue eyes peered out from under bushy white brows, drilling into whatever he looked at. *-The Eye of the World*

   Note how he appears to be juggling, and has white hair and long white mustaches.

   [image]
7. [Aviendha](http://wot.wikia.com/wiki/Aviendha)

   > Blue-green eyes and reddish hair cut short except for a narrow tail that hung to her shoulders. -*The Dragon Reborn*

   With red hair, and a white shirt/blouse indicative of a Wise One, here we have the lovely Aviendha.

   [image]
8. [Berelain sur Paendrag Paeron](http://wot.wikia.com/wiki/Berelain_sur_Paendrag_Paeron)

   > Her black hair swept to pale shoulders, and her dress of the finest red silk left those shoulders bare, along with a considerable expanse of what Mat noted as an admirable bosom. *- The Shadow Rising*

   She appears to fit the bill: she is regarded as one of the most attractive women in the series, other then Lanfear.

   [image]
9. [Zarine ni Bashere t'Aybara(Faile)](http://wot.wikia.com/wiki/Zarine_ni_Bashere_t'Aybara)

   > She was young - no older than he was, perhaps - and tall for a woman, with black hair to her shoulders. A nose that just missed being too large and too bold, a generous mouth, high cheekbones, and dark, slightly tilted eyes. He could not quite decide whether she was beautiful or not. -*The Dragon Reborn*

   Notice the sharp nose, tilted eyes, and high cheek bones.

   [image]
10. [el'Nynaeve ti al'Meara Mandragoran](http://wot.wikia.com/wiki/El'Nynaeve_ti_al'Meara_Mandragoran)

    > Nynaeve was about 5'4" tall, with big dark eyes (though not so big as Egwene’s) and dark hair which she normally wore in a braid as thick as a man’s wrist which hung to her waist. She was undeniably pretty, and some thought her beautiful. *-Companion*

    Another defining feature is the *ki'sain*, the red dot on her forehead, traditionally to show she was married to a Malkier, aka Lan.

    [image]
11. [Perrin Aybara](http://wot.wikia.com/wiki/Perrin_Aybara)

    > Half a head shorter than Rand. the curly-haired blacksmith's apprentice was so stocky as to seem a man and a half wide, with arms and shoulders thick enough to rival those of Master Luhhan himself. -*Eye of the World*

    Large chest and arms, curly hair, and a beard. Check!

    [image]
12. [Logain Ablar](http://wot.wikia.com/wiki/Logain_Ablar)

    > He was tall and handsome, short of middle years, with long, dark curling hair. -*The Great Hunt*

    Long dark hair, appears to be a tall man. Notice the dragon pin on his lapel to signify Asha'man.

    [image]
13. [Elmindreda_Farshaw](http://wot.wikia.com/wiki/Elmindreda_Farshaw)

    > Moiraine was standing at the end of the hall with a slender girl not much taller than herself. At least, Rand thought it was a girl, though her dark hair was cut short and she wore a man's shirt and trousers. [...] the crop-haired young woman who had been with Moiraine when he came out of the bath chamber, still dressed in a boy's coat and breeches. She was a little older than he was, he thought, with dark eyes even bigger than Egwene's, and oddly intent. -*Eye of the World*

    Short hair and pants: totally Min, though the artist seems to have ignored her curly hair.

    [image]
14. [Elayne Trakand](http://wot.wikia.com/wiki/Elayne_Trakand)

    > long, red-gold curls [...] tall for a girl, and beautiful, her face a perfect oval framed by that mass of sunburst curls, her lips full and red, her eyes bluer than he could believe. *-The Eye of the World*

    Red-gold curly/wavy hair. Check!

    [image]
15. [Siuan Sanche](http://wot.wikia.com/wiki/Siuan_Sanche)

    > About 5'5" tall, she was fair-skinned, blue-eyed and more than handsome but less than beautiful. After she was deposed and stilled, she looked young, about twenty-two or twenty-three, and no longer like an Aes Sedai. Men in Lugard considered her pretty, which astonished her. Her eyes could flash fire and bore holes in stone when she wanted them to. *-Companion*

    Fair-skinned, with eyes that bore holes into stone. Check!

    > Next to her eventual Warder also helps.

    [image]
16. [Gareth Bryne](http://wot.wikia.com/wiki/Gareth_Bryne)

    > A bluff, blocky man stood bareheaded by the Queen's right hand in the red of the Queen's Guards [...] His temples were heavy with gray, but he looked as strong and immovable as a rock. -*Eye of the World*

    Older military man, with a lion on the chest to symbolize Andor, plus being next to Siuan.

    [image]
17. [Al'Lan Mandragoran](http://wot.wikia.com/wiki/Al'Lan_Mandragoran)

    > His clothes were a dark grayish green that would have faded into lead or shadow, and his cloak swirled through shades of gray and green and brown as it shifted in the wind. It almost seemed to disappear, that cloak, fading into whatever lay beyond it. His hair was long, and gray at the temples, held back from his face by a narrow leather headband. That face was made from stony planes and angles, weathered but unlined despite the gray in his hair. -*Eye of the World*

    Blocky face, long hair, headband, Warder's cloak - must be Lan.

    [image]
18. [Lanfear](http://wot.wikia.com/wiki/Lanfear)

    > She was all in white, her dress divided for riding and belted in silver, and her boots, peeking out from under her hems, were tooled in silver, too. Even her saddle was white, and silver-mounted... But it was the woman herself—she was perhaps Nynaeve’s age, he thought—who held his eyes. She was tall, for one thing; a hand taller and she could almost look him in the eyes. For another, she was beautiful, ivory-pale skin contrasting sharply with long, night-dark hair and black eyes. - *The Great Hunt*

    Creamy white skin, dark hair, in her signature white dress with silver jewelry - must be Lanfear.

    [image]
19. [Rand al'Thor, The Dragon Reborn](http://wot.wikia.com/wiki/Rand_al'Thor)

    > Rand was approximately 6'6" tall and weighed 235 pounds, with broad shoulders, a deep chest and a narrow waist. He had dark reddish hair, and eyes that seemed now gray, now blue; women could get quite lyrical about his eyes. He was very good-looking; many women thought him either pretty or beautiful. *-Companion*

    Red hair, blue/grey eyes, dragon tattoos on his arms, and the never healing wound on his side, this must be the one and only, the Dragon Reborn!

    [image]

Comment: +1, but I was *hoping* for an answer based on reasoning and deduction (e.g. braid => Nynaeve, white lions => Elayne, pale with moon earrings => Lanfear) rather than finding pictures on the internet. If you include some nice deductions for all 19 characters, or alternatively quotes from the books to describe their appearance, then you'll get a big fat bounty.

Comment: The biggest challenges are going to be a) distinguishing between Egwene and Siuan and b) identifying Logain and Berelain.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Two physical features that distinguish Siuan from Egwene are Siuan's 'striking' blue eyes and hair that's closer to shoulder length Although Egwene no longer braids her hair, she never mentions cutting it, so presumably her length might be similar to Nynaeve's. More concrete identifying features in the images above include Siuan's Blue Ajah shall (which clearly separates her from Egwene), and the Twised Stone Ring sleep weaver worn by Egwene.

Comment: @DavidH Yep, the eyes are a good one. The shawl, though, isn't visible in the main image. And I thought Siuan had a twisted-ring ter'angreal for a long time as well?

Comment: @Randal'Thor Actually, Siuan has to put a lot of effort and sneakiness into getting access to the ring for a night, since she has to go through Leane, who in turn has to go through the Hall. Siuan doesn't get permanent possession of a ring until Leane is captured in CoT, and Hall simply presumes she had the ring with her at that time. Also, Egwene is the only character I can remember who ever wore the ring casually while waking.

Comment: the ring is to emphasis egwene as a dreamer, and david is right, Siuan most likely left the ring in her tent when she wasnt using it, hidden since she was supposed to have it. and she was wearing low cut dresses so having it on a necklace was most likely not happening.

Comment: I'm going to give you the first bounty since you answered first, then another bounty to CHEESE since they also did what I was hoping for, then a third bounty to you since you deserve to have the biggest bounty. Drinks are on me tonight :-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor I'll come drinking with you guys but only if you *put your damn shirt back on*

Comment: @Randal'Thor  shots shots shots!

Comment: Quotes from the Companion are nice, but they don't make up for quotes from the books themselves - hint hint ;-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor this answer would be 3x as long if we found book quotes, espcially since most of these characters are only described in pieces throughout the series, so for lengths sake their compaion complete descriptions are neat and straight to the point,  the books also change descriptions depending on the character whos describing them, like tuon gets more and more attractive as matt falls in love with her, and so does Faile as perrin falls in love with her, skewing the descriptions

Comment: Most of the Companion quotes could be replaced by book quotes of similar length, usually from the first time the character is described - just like you did for Moiraine. Would you mind if I find some and edit them into your answer? All this 5'11'' stuff makes it sound less like WoT and more like a catalogue or something.

Comment: The only ones left to find book quotes for now are Egwene, Tuon, Mat, Nynaeve, Siuan, and Rand. That's few enough for me to award you the bounty. Enjoy your spoils :-)

Comment: 9 is definitely not Faile - it's Aeryn Sun.

Answer (score 14):

I am referring to the numbers from the numbered image provided by @Rand al'Thor in his question, though it would be better with some freehand circles (if those are freehand, then you really are Rand al'Thor and you can control the Pattern.)

[image]

1. Wearing blue might mean Blue Ajah, but that is not enough.  What really defines here is the *kesiera* on her forehead.  Yes, ladies and gentlemen:  it's **Moiraine.**
2. Again, the blue dress could mean Blue Ajah, but she was never Blue Ajah.  Who?  **Egwene.**  How do I know it is Egwene?  She is short, has long, dark, unbraided hair, and the final one is that around her neck is a necklace with what seems to be the dream ter'angreal.
3. By hair, coloring, and short stature, this is almost definitely **Tuon.**
4. **Mat.**  The long, wide-brimmed hat and the jovial smile are screaming Mat.  I'm sure if we could see the rest of his body there would be an *ashandarei*, a scarf, and some number of foxhead medallions spilling out of his pockets.
5. The only character in the series with only one eye

   > other than Mat, who has actual hair, (isn't it weird that the two biggest cursers are the ones with one eye?)

   is **Uno.**
6. **Thom Merrilin.**  Period.
7. White blouse?  Defiant look on her face?  Reddish hair?  This must be **Aviendha.**
8. I might consider calling this Berelain just because of the nonexistent neckline.  At the time I did this, the only major characters left were Faile and Berelain.  The latter's description says she is beautiful, tall, pale, with large black eyes.  I concluded that this was **Berelain.**
9. This was a hard one, and the last one I did.  By the time I got here, there was a gaping hole in my list of major characters: Faile.  I thought this was probably Faile, as she looked like she had a strong personality, but I didn't want to end on such a speculatory note, so I did some digging.  Turns out that her description on [the wiki](http://wot.wikia.com/wiki/Zarine_ni_Bashere_t%27Aybara) gives here a bold nose, black hair, and high cheekbones, so if she is anyone, she is **Faile.**
10. A woman wearing a yellow dress, a braid, and a *ki'sain*?  Looks like she just ate Mat's medallion?  Check!  **Nynaeve.**
11. The wide shoulders and look on his face might push me in the right directions, but it is the beard that sets it for me.  A quick wot.wikia [search for beard](http://wot.wikia.com/wiki/Special:Search?search=Beard&fulltext=Search&page=1&ns0=1&ns112=1&ns500=1&ns502=1) shows that Elyas and Perrin are the only major characters with beards.  This can only be **Perrin**, who is much bigger.
12. Obviously this is an Asha'man because of his black coat and dragon pin.  There are many Asha'man characters, but only four major full Asha'man: Logain, M'Hael, Flinn, and Narishma.  Just by hair, Flinn and Narishma are out (one has braids with bells, one only a fringe of white hair.  M'Hael has a clean-shaven face, so he is not this man.  Therefore he is almost definitely **Logain.**
13. A slim, pretty girl that is wearing a coat and breeches instead of a dress can only be **Min.**
14. **Elayne Trakand.**  The hair, proud look, and white lions on the red dress give it away.
15. Wearing poor clothes and staring daggers at Gareth Bryne.  Holding what seems like his laundry...I must say, this looks like **Siuan Sanche.**
16. What really gives this away is the fact that his armor has a lion on the chest among crimson.  An Andoran general is **Gareth Bryne.**
17. He wears a *hadori*, as nobody else in the series does.  This must be **Lan.**
18. A black-haired beautiful woman wearing a white dress and looking seductively at the camera is probably **Lanfear.**  Also, the constant references to the moon in her jewellery are a giveaway: Selene was the Greek moon-goddess.
19. **RAND AL'THOR**!

Comment: You'll also get a bounty for this, but you may have to wait a bit (see [my last comment](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/125044/who-are-all-these-wheel-of-time-characters/125045#comment312275_125045) on Himarm's answer).

Comment: @Randal'Thor That's a lot of bounties, I had to read that a couple of times to figure it out.

Comment: Pfft. The one that everyone says is Faile (#9) is obviously Claudia Black.