# Is Rand al'Thor ginger?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

A [recent question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/125044/) featuring drawings of *Wheel of Time* characters got me thinking about this.

My understanding is that, in *The Eye of the World*, Rand al'Thor's hair is described as having a reddish tinge to it.  This is consistent with some of the early cover art, which shows him to have auburn but not entirely red hair (click to enlarge):

[image]

But over time, artwork related to Rand al'Thor has progressively shown hair hues tending to full-on red and even orange:

[image][image]

**What is Rand al'Thor's actual hair colour?  Has it changed over time?**

Comment: Uh, isn't this sort of a personal question?

Comment: "Ginger" isn't just about red hair. It's about a combination of red hair, pale skin, and freckles!

Comment: @Axelrod : Well, having grown up in the UK, we would regularly use "ginger" to describe folks who only meet the hair part of your list. :-)

Comment: @Axelrod : Also, I liked the title.  ;-)

Comment: Drat, I was too late to answer this one!

Comment: @Randal'Thor : Of course I was hoping it would be you!  But the issue of whether his hair has changed over time is still unresolved...

Comment: I'll have a look in the books later on and see if I can come up with anything :-)

Comment: Does the carpet match the drapes do you mean?

Comment: @ATB Your audacity has completely floored me. I guess now it's curtains for me!

Comment: No. He's [rude and not ginger](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EGs_ryZ9bfY).

Comment: @Randal'Thor : Hehe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rand has dark red hair. He is also described as essentially being "white" but with a darker tone, so tanned, which is not a fit with the pale skin and freckles associated with "ginger"

> Rand was approximately 6'6" tall and weighed 235 pounds, with broad shoulders, a deep chest and a narrow waist. He had dark reddish hair, and eyes that seemed now gray, now blue; women could get quite lyrical about his eyes. He was very good-looking; many women thought him either pretty or beautiful. *-The Wheel Of Time Companion.*

Its important to note that the Companion is a recent publication, and depicts Rand how he looked at the end of the series.

Here is the original cover art of the hard cover.

[image]

Notice its red, almost brown, so a dark red hair.

I found this instance in The Gathering Storm (book 12)

> He had reddish gold hair, maybe suggesting some Aiel blood.

This, however, was written by Brandon Sanderson and not Robert Jordan, and is the only instance ive found of lighter colored hair.

Again in book (13) Towers of Midnight it is again described as dark red.

> He had deep red hair and he wore ragged clothing:

Comment: That cover art is clearly unreliable, since Lan doesn't wear a helmet.

Comment: I'm gonna read the series, I was looking for a good book and **fortunately** found a series. Thanks guys!

Comment: @Randal'Thor he has worn a helmet on occasion during the series.

Comment: @apollo Great, another new recruit to the world of WoT! :-D

Comment: 'He is also described as essentially being "white" but with a darker tone, so tanned, which is not a fit with the pale skin and freckles associated with "ginger"' Here's why I think this^ is false: When Rand is captured by the Queen of Andor in Eye of the World, he claims to be from the Two Rivers. When the Aes Sedai in the court disputes this claim, she pulls back his sleeve to show the part of his skin that hasn't been tanned by the sun. That part of his skin is very pale, which the Aes Sedai claims is evidence that he is lying. In this scene, it is revealed that Rand has very pale skin.